# org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel is thread safe?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

We are having multiple models to load during the run time to predict based on the trained model. And our is mulitthreaded application , so If I load the model using org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.load("path of the mode")  will this work properly . Below is the reason why I am asking this doubt .

1. I haven't seen anywhere mentioning that org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel is thread safe ?
2. Even If it is not , Can I use this, because at the same time 2 or more thread could use the same object of org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel, will this impact anything ?

Thanks,
Param.

Comment: I believe that if you respect the principle of immutablity (using val in scala for your objects), you won't have to worry about sharing across processes